# Is Tuple2 and Pair the same thing or not?

Tags: scala

Is there a difference between classes `Tuple2` and `Pair` in scala?

It seems to me they do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. both are same

```
type Pair[+A, +B] = Tuple2[A, B]
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L1 line 227